# pdb.set_trace() not working

Tags: python, set, trace, pdb

When I insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in my code, it shows an error message:

> 'module' object has attribute 'set_trace'

In the `pdb.py` file, there is the `def set_trace()` function. How can it not work?

Has anyone had the same problem and knows how to solve this?

Comment: This is almost certainly due to some other issues in your code - could you paste the smallest code excerpt you can that reproduces the issue?

Comment: change that to `import pdb; print pdb.__file__ ; pdb.set_trace()` you might not import the standard `pdb.py` file.

Comment: did you mean `"'module' object has NO attribute 'set_trace'"`?

Comment: Is your script called `pdb.py` by any chance?

Comment: Thanks guys. Anthon and wim are right. I really did not import the standard pdb.py. Instead, I import another module having the same name.

Answer (score 3):

if the python file that you are running is `code.py` please change the name. For some reasons `code.py` or `pdb.py` files can not use pdb package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

change the name file pdb.py same bdb_test.py it run with me

Answer (score 0):

What Python version are you using?
I can reproduce that error if I try to `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` on `Python 3.8`.

Try to use `breakpoint()` instead (has basically the same purpose), it worked for me!

Cheers,
Andres

Answer (score 0):

If your script is named `pdb.py`, that will cause this error. Change the name of your script.